# @IBOutlet pageControl is invalid

Tags: ios, swift, коллекции, page

Я пытаюсь добавить **@IBOulet** **pageControl** на **viewController** для отображения текущей страницы и общего количества страниц.

Мой collectionView находится внутри обычного **viewController**. Но когда я создаю **@IBOutlet** внутри **viewController** я получаю ошибку:

**"The pageControl outlet from the DetailViewController to the UIPageControl is invalid. Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content."**

Первое что не понятно что за повторяющийся контект?

Я понимаю что вопрос был задан миллион раз, но я пробовал что советуют и ничего не получается...

PageControl у меня один в main.storyboard
[image: pageControll]

Если нужен код, то он ниже:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - IBOutlet's
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var hallImages: Hall?

    var currentPage = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 626
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
    // MARK: - CollectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let imagesHall = hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count else {
            return 0
        }
        return imagesHall
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionViewCell

        if let imagesHalls = hallImages?.ImagesHalls[indexPath.item] {
            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesHalls))
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Как мне добавить **pageControl** в **coolectionView**, **collectionCell** или во **viewController** (не знаю уже как лучше)?

Comment: Штоби создать оутлет в таком виде как сейчас вам нужно добавлять ево в класс целла вашего collectionView.

Comment: а дальше что с ним сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторяющийся контент в Вашем случае - ячейка коллекции, в которую вы поместили PageController в StoryBoard. Вынесите его из коллекции. Например поставьте ниже Price Label.

Comment: Я почему то думал есть какой-то обходной путь чтобы привзать pageControl к ячейке(( Ну ладно, спасибо